# Classify the 1000000 elements on the basis of 1000 tests

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 1000000 elements with parameters (a,b,c,d,e,f). I have to classify them into 2 classes (whether f(a,b,c,d,e,f) less than `N` or not). The calculations for classification takes too long time, however, I need the result asap.

I have come up with the following idea: make the calculations for 1000 elements and classify them. On the basis of the classification, develop an analytical formula g(a,b,c,d,e,f), which would help me to quickly classify other elements (with some probability, of course).

What is the way of developing this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of machine learning algorithms that would help you do this classification problem. I think that that's your best bet. Here are a few suggestions off the top of my head:

- $k$ nearest neighbours
- random forest
- support vector machines
- neural networks
- linear discriminant analysis
- naive Bayes classifier

Using several of them (preferably an odd number since you only have 2 classes) and having them vote to get the final result is also an idea.